# Could not load module metadata from

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I am stuck for a day now trying to solve this issue I just updated my android studio but when I open the old project  it is showing error

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\NEELAY\.gradle\caches\modules- 
2\metadata-2.36\descriptors\com.android.support\multidex- 
instrumentation\1.0.2\5ac5911800d0dfe0ba2d29f224b8c2fb\descriptor.bin
Unexpected metadata type found.
```

I followed some question also which say to uninstall the android support repository and reinstall but it is not working tried gradle.setting is also proper . Now i have no idea how to solve this issue any help will be helpfull.
Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fireapp.manoj.template">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

this is the manifest code but dont know why it is showing as setting.gradle
any idea why is it because of the gradle update

Comment: Please post your android manifest

Comment: thx mate but dont know why it is coming like setting.gradle

Comment: Hey @Neelay what was the problem i'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Smith It happens when the download is not done properly so i just deleted that file and android studio then ask you to download that file hope this will help you

Comment: but i tried deleting file and then again making project but still doesnt work

Comment: Bro so you are opening the the old android studio file in my case the manifest file was comming as the gradle setting file so I deleated and download then I simply make another project and just copied the files in it dont know but for me it worked with me

Comment: Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not load module metadata from /home/code/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/descriptors/com.android.support.test/runner/1.0.2/da4190074d36b292f150a83ad82b6bb8/descriptor.bin
Buffer underflow.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: this is the error i'm getting

Comment: @Smith see your setting .gradle is it like the manifest ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Remove the caches.**

Step 1 : Open the terminal

Step 2 : paste cd C:\Users\NEELAY.gradle\ (Navigate to .gradle folder)

Step 3 : rm -r caches\

Step 4 : Now clean or rebuild the project

Answer (score 7):

Just clear metadata-2.36 folder in caches (no need to remove entire cache folder like suggested above) and do gradle clean build. I also faced the same issue and by following above step, my build became successful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto gradle path which is given in error. like: `C:\Users\NEELAY\.gradle`
2. Delete the whole gradle folder (`.gradle` folder may be)
3. Restart android studio and try to run now

If at 3. not worked:

4. After all this (after deleting `.gradle`) uninstall android studio and reinstall it.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may arise when the android studio couldn't update all the dependencies.
Go to

`file->project structure->dependencies`

And make sure you update all the dependencies listed on the right side.

If it still pops out any issue delete the Gradle folder in the project and rebuild the project.